# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte while reading a text file

Tags: python-3.x, gensim, word2vec

I am training a word2vec model, using about 700 text files as my corpus. But, when I start reading the files after the preprocessing step, I get the mentioned error. The code is as follows

```
class MyCorpus(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        for i in ceo_path:                              /// ceo_path contains abs path of all text files
            file = open(i, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
            text = file.read()

            ###########                                        
            ###########                                 /// text preprocessing steps
            ###########
            
            yield final_text                            /// returns preprocessed text


sentences = MyCorpus()
logging.basicConfig(format="%(levelname)s - %(asctime)s: %(message)s", datefmt= '%H:%M:%S', level=logging.INFO)

# training the model
cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
w2v_model = Word2Vec(min_count=5,
                     iter=30,
                     window=3,
                     size=200,
                     sample=6e-5,
                     alpha=0.025,
                     min_alpha=0.0001,
                     negative=20,
                     workers=cores-1,
                     sg=1)
w2v_model.build_vocab(sentences)
w2v_model.train(sentences, total_examples=w2v_model.corpus_count, epochs=30, report_delay=1)
w2v_model.save('ceo1.model')
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/name/PycharmProjects/prac2/hbs_word2vec.py", line 131, in <module>
    w2v_model.build_vocab(sentences)
  File "C:\Users\name\PycharmProjects\prac1\venv\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\base_any2vec.py", line 921, in build_vocab
    total_words, corpus_count = self.vocabulary.scan_vocab(
  File "C:\Users\name\PycharmProjects\prac1\venv\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py", line 1403, in scan_vocab
    total_words, corpus_count = self._scan_vocab(sentences, progress_per, trim_rule)
  File "C:\Users\name\PycharmProjects\prac1\venv\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py", line 1372, in _scan_vocab
    for sentence_no, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
  File "C:/Users/name/PycharmProjects/prac2/hbs_word2vec.py", line 65, in __iter__
    text = file.read()
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I am not able to understand the error as I am new to this. I was not getting the error in reading the text files when I wasn't using the **iter** function and sending the data in chunks as I am doing currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like one of your files doesn't have proper `utf-8`-encoded text.

(Your `Word2Vec`-related code probably isn't necessary for hitting the error, at all. You could probably trigger the same error with just: `sentences_list = list(MyCorpus())`.)

To find which file, two different possibilities might be:

1. Change your `MyCorpus` class so that it prints the path of each file before it tries to read it.
2. Add a Python `try: ... except UnicodeDecodeError: ...` statement around the `read`, and when the exception is caught, print the offending filename.

Once you know the file involved, you may want to fix the file, or change the code to be able to handle the files you have.

Maybe they're not really in `utf-8` encoding, in which case you'd specify a different `encoding`.

Maybe just one or a few have problems, and it's be OK to just print their names for later investigation, and skip them. (You could use the exception-handling approach above to do that.)

Maybe, those that aren't `utf-8` are always in some other platform-specific encoding, so when `utf-8` fails, you could try a 2nd encoding.

Separately, when you solve the encoding issue, your iterable `MyCorpus` is not yet returning whet the `Word2Vec` class expects.

It doesn't want full text plain strings. It needs those texts to already be broken up into individual word-tokens.

(Often, simply performing a `.split()` on a string is close-enough-to-real-tokenization to try as a starting point, but usually, projects use some more-sophisticated punctuation-aware tokenization.)

Comment: Yep! this approach worked. There was a .model file somewhere in between. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I was getting a memory error after running the following code can u explain why and how to deal with it? Thanks!

Comment: If you have a separate memory error, you should post a separate question with the full details of how it's triggered. Can't really guess what's happening here, without even the error message/stack!